# .Net Impersonation Issue When User Part Of Administrators

Tags: asp.net, .net, impersonation

I am troubleshooting an ASP.Net project issue. I have a network share, and I'm using impersonation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/aspnet/implement-impersonation.

Here's an odd issue I found: if I impersonate a user named domain\foo to enumerate files using `Directory.EnumerateFiles`, I run into UnauthorizedAccessException for one of the two test cases:

In both cases user foo is part of the administrators group.

1. Test case 1: If I explicitly give the user NTFS permissions to the folder of the share, I don't get access denied (not that administrators group has full control to the folder).
2. Test case 2: If I remove the user from the permissions list, keeping in mind that administrators still has full control, I get the UnauthorizedAccessException.

I cannot explain the above behavior. In both cases I would expect to be able to enumerate files successfully. Is this a bug, or am I not taking into account some key piece?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by using a logon type of LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS